# Why does a 1x1 convolution layer work for feature reduction in a Neural Network Regression?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, feature-selection

I would love some insight on this question - I've tried to find explanations in the literature, but I'm stumped. So I am building a neural network (using Keras) to solve a regression problem. I have ~500,000 samples with 20,000 features each,  and am trying to predict a numerical output. Think predicting a house price based on a bunch of numerical measurements of the house, yard, etc. The features are arranged alphabetically so their neighboring features are fairly meaningless.

When I first tried to create a neural network, it suffered from severe overfitting if I provided all 20,000 features - manually reducing it to 1,000 features improved performance massively.

I read about 1x1 convolutional neural networks being used for feature reduction, but it was all used for images and 2D inputs.

So I built a basic neural network with 3 layers:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=1, activation="relu", input_shape=(n_features,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

I also reshaped my training set as input from `n_samples, n_features` to:
`reshaped= X_train.reshape(n_samples, n_features, 1)` to conform with the expected input of Conv1D.

Contrary to normal dense neural networks, this works as though I manually selected the top performing features. My questions is - why does this work?? Replacing the convolution layer with a dense layer completely kills the performance. Does this even have anything to do with feature reduction or is something else going on entirely?

I thought 2d images use 1x1 convolutions to reduce the channel dimensions of the image - but I only have 1 channel with 1x1 convolution, so what's being reduced? Does setting my 1D convolution layer filters to 128 mean I have selected 128 features which are subsequently fed to the next layer? Are the features selected based on loss back propagation?

I'm having a lot of trouble visualizing what is happening to the information from my features.

Lastly, what if I were to then add another convolution layer down the road? Is there a way to conceptualize what would happen if I added another 1x1 layer? Is it further subsampling of features?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's augment your model with a Dense layer with 128 units and observe the summary for two models.

**Conv Model**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
n_features = 1000 # your sequence length
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=1, activation="relu", input_shape=(n_features,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 1000, 128)         256       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 128000)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 100)               12800100  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 12,800,457
Trainable params: 12,800,457
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**FC Model**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
n_features = 1000 # your sequence length
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu", input_shape=(n_features,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 1000, 128)         256       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 128000)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 100)               12800100  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 12,800,457
Trainable params: 12,800,457
Non-trainable params: 0
_____________________________
```

As you can see both models have an identical number of parameters in each layer. But inherently they are completely different.

[image]

Let's say we have the inputs with length 4 only. A 1 convolution with 3 filters will use 3 separate kernels on those 4 inputs, each kernel will operate on a single element of input at a time as we have chosen kernel_size = 1. So, each kernel is just a single scalar value which will be multiplied with the input array one element at a time (bias will be added). The thing here is the 1 convolution doesn't look anywhere besides the current input meaning **it doesn't have any spatial freedom, it only looks at current input point at a time.** (this will become useful for later explanation)

Now, with dense/fc layer each neuron is connected to each input, meaning the fc layer has full spatial freedom, it looks everywhere. The equivalent Conv layer will be something with a kernel_size = 1000 (the actual input length).

**So, why Conv1D 1 convolution is maybe performing better?**

- Well, it's hard to tell without actually looking into data properties. But one guess would be you're using features that don't have any spatial dependency.

You have chosen the features randomly and probably mixing them (looking at many input features at once doesn't help but learns some extra noise). This could be the reason why you're getting better performance with a Conv layer which only looks one feature at a time instead of an FC layer which looks at all of them and mixes them.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great illustration! One thing I'm still confused about - in your example of a Conv1D with 128 units operating on 1000 features, is the mapping of a particular feature to the unit random? Ie. does it just randomly pick 128 out of a 1000 features?

Comment: No, not all, there are 128 filters (vectors) which are applied on each point of 1000 inputs. Here's a simple guide: https://medium.com/@jon.froiland/convolutional-neural-networks-for-sequence-processing-part-1-420dd9b500

Also, don't forget to upvote/accept answer if they are helpful.